# CoCreateInstance: Create a COM instance defined in a .NET library?

Tags: c++, .net, com, com-interop

I've created a COM library defined in an IDL, it has an "entrypoint" called IFoo:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(789b4d46-4028-4196-8412-4c5c8ef86caa),
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IFoo: IUnknown
{
    HRESULT HelloWorld();
};
```

I've implemented this in my C# library like so:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("45b50f1e-d551-4be0-b52a-7ec075840114")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IFoo))]
class Foo: IFoo
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I compiled this, and registered it with:

```
regasm.exe foo.dll
```

Everything looks good thus far.

Now, how do I create an instance of this in my C++ program?  I think the right function is ::CoCreateInstance:

```
::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
IUnknown *pUnk = 0;
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(???, 
                                NULL, 
                                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                                __uuidof(IFoo), 
                               (void**)&pUnk);
```

Is this the right way to create an instance of this class?  If so, what goes in "???" above?

I *think* the class's UUID ("45b50f1e-d551-4be0-b52a-7ec075840114" above) should go there, but I can't figure out how to manually create an IID from this GUID string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, I was right, the class's UUID goes there, but getting it was something I didn't expect:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("45b50f1e-d551-4be0-b52a-7ec075840114")) Cls;
```

Then:

```
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Cls), 
                                NULL, 
                                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                                __uuidof(IFoo), 
                               (void**)&pUnk);
```

This fixed the problem and worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `MIDL` to compile your IDL file into set of C++ files and include them into your C++ program. Have in mind that interface is not the "entry point" and you are going to need the class object in your IDL too.

Another way to create a COM client in C++ is Microsoft specific `#import` directive, but I am not sure if it is compatible with .NET-based components. If you can create a .tlb file for your .NET component, you can just add the needed stuff like this:

```
#import "MyLibrary.tlb"
```

This directive has lots of options. Check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa.aspx) for details.

Comment: I did use MIDL to compile down to a set of C++ files.  I used this to produce a .lib I link against and a .h I include.  I think you missed the point of the question, how to activate and create an instance of this class I made in .Net.  Unless, of course, I'm misunderstanding your reply.  =)

Comment: @LCC One of the files created by MIDL (namely `your_lib_name_i.c`) contains the definitions of all GUIDS in project and `your_lib_name.h` has the declarations of these GUIDS. By including these files into your C++ you will be able to use constants like `CLSID_Foo` in your COM functions calls.

Comment: You may have missed the CLSID of your class in your MIDL-generated files because your IDL is missing the class declaration

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I didn't define the class there, so that's part of the problem.  Thanks!